# Get value of new dynamically appended rows JQuery Ajax in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have already fetch data from database and display it in the view in a Laravel Project:

```
// get price
$('select[name="state"]').on('change', function() {
    var stateID = $(this).val();

    if (stateID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'invoice/getPurchaseItems/' + stateID,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $("#brand").append(`<td>${value}</td>`);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">No</th>
            <th scope="col">Inventory </th>
            <th scope="col">Product </th>
            <th scope="col"> Qty in Inventory </th>
            <th scope="col">Unit</th>
            <th scope="col">Unit Price </th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Price </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="brand">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get value of new dynamically appended rows in order to calculate and store it in database.

Comment: Please can you elaborate more ? What do want to achieve ?

Comment: in the table `tbody` I fetch and append values into multiple dynamically rows, now I want those values to store in database. Like how to get `<td>${value}</td>` value after it's appended in the controller?

Comment: use class name in each `td` or hidden inputs ? Also data should be submit using `ajax` or `form` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `<td>` in `<tr>` and then append it to the `<tbody>`

```
// get price
$('select[name="state"]').on('change', function() {
    var stateID = $(this).val();

    if (stateID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'invoice/getPurchaseItems/' + stateID,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                let newData = '<tr>';
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    newData += `<td>${value}</td>`;
                });
                newData += '</tr>';
                $("#brand").append(newData);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I needed to get these appended values in controller and store it into database.